# curl will not return while performing a HEAD request

Tags: node.js, curl, etag

I am creating resources on a node server and attaching an ETag to each one of them. I am using the method found in this question [What encoding should I use to properly generate an ETag with crypto in nodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327068/what-encoding-should-i-use-to-properly-generate-an-etag-with-crypto-in-nodejs) for generating the ETags. However, when I do a `HEAD` request on command line using curl, like:

```
$ curl -i -u username:password -X HEAD http://localhost:3000/aResource/0
```

the answer is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: "1a37c148692f92ad6c97887f77c873e6"
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sat, 26 Oct 2013 01:06:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

^C
$
```

and I have to specifically press `Control-C` in order to see the command prompt again. On the other hand, I find this strange, because the way I am handling the `HEAD` request is through app.head on node and after the authentication I am calling the function:

```
function serveResourceEtag(req, res) {
    console.log("Following route through HEAD");
    var anID    = parseInt(req.params[resourceID], "utf8");
    if (anID < serverData.resourceEtags.length) {
        res.writeHead (200, {"ETag": "\"" + serverData.resourceEtags[anID] + "\"", "Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end();
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead (404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end();
    }
};
```

In other words, even though I have the res.end(); command in the end, the transmission for some reason has not stopped. As far as I understand a `HEAD` request should get the same header as a `GET` request. The difference with a `GET` is that in the case of `HEAD` we do not have the body of a `GET` request. Can you tell what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: It's not your server's fault. When I do `curl -i -X HEAD http://google.com` I have to kill curl to get back to the prompt, which is odd, because a curl GET request actually does drop me back to the prompt. Go figure.

Comment: Wow! I did not think of trying something that trivial. Please post the answer and I will accept. Thanks for your time. I would have kept on reading about HEAD requests and node documentation endlessly.

Comment: Haha, ya sometimes you just have to poke it with a stick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right about the behaviour of the HTTP methods, it's just the curl that's wrong, you want:

```
curl -I -u username:password http://localhost:3000/aResource/0
```

not -X HEAD which is saying use a HEAD method of HTTP rather than a GET which only returns the headers

Comment: Actually the truth seems to be somewhere in between. All I had to change for curl to return was to make the lowercase i to capital I like you have it above. Then -X HEAD works as expected. I am accepting anyway. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Removing "-X HEAD" causes curl to make a 'GET' request. That is, fetch response headers and response body, although you displayed only the headers using the -I option.
Like @MightyMouse said, changing -i to -I (only) is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your server's fault. When I do `curl -i -X HEAD http://google.com` I have to kill curl to get back to the prompt, which is odd, because a curl GET request actually does drop me back to the prompt.

Comment: Sorry, Dan, I will actually accept Matt's suggestion since the capital I does make curl to return. I have to go back and read the manual. But still, as I write to Matt, if one uses -I (instead of -i) and moreover -X HEAD as I had, everything works the way I expected. Thanks again for all the help.